# Как изменить значение background-size с помощью jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Есть такой код:

```
$('.header-x').css({'background-size':  screenWidth + ' auto'});
```

Но он не работает.

Может кто поможет с правильным решением?

Comment: А такой вариант не подойдёт? `$('.header-x').css({'background-size': '100% auto'});` Или лучше `.header-x { background-size: 100% auto; }` Разумеется только если ширина `.header-x` у Вас равна screenWidth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
setTimeout(() => {

  screenWidth = 50;
  document.querySelector('.header-x').style.backgroundSize = screenWidth+'px auto'

}, 666);
```

```css
.header-x{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/travel-roundline/512/wall-512.png);
  
  // Ваш косяк в том, что вы забыли единицы измерения.
  // Так это не работает:
  background-size: 50 auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class='header-x'></div>
```